# Feynman diagram for neutron capture

Tags: quantum-field-theory, nuclear-physics, radiation, feynman-diagrams

I am studying experimental methods for detecting neutrons. Having recently studied QFT, I wondered if there was a way to describe this type of process through a Feynman diagram.

For example for the process
$${}_{2}^3{\rm He} + n \longrightarrow {}_1^3{\rm H} + p $$ if it is possible to describe this interaction in terms of quarks.

This question came to me trying to find a formal explanation of the resonances that the cross section presents as shown in the figure:
[image]

Comment: Was part of your course not devoted to learning of the possible interactions between charged fermions such as quarks and Feynman rules?

Comment: It certainly was. But with the basic knowledge I learned I am unable to extend the concepts that I learned to the case of the process that I reported in the question.